# Find maximum $n$ satisfying $(2^n)|A$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find maximum $n$ satisfying  $(2^n)|A$. Where $A=63.64.65.66.67.68 .\cdots. 130$ .

Comment: Those periods should be $\cdot$s or equivalently $\times$s for multiplication I presume. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did your first attempt fail?

Comment: In response to the deleted answer: the base-$p$ logarithm and highest power of $p$ dividing an integer can be arbitrarily far apart.

Comment: There is a fairly explicit formula, by Legendre,  for the highest power of $2$ dividing $n!$ for some given $n.$ So, do $130!$ and $62!$ and subtract. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory OR http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml

Comment: There is a fancy but computationally easy way. But you can do it the hard way. The number $64$ contributes $6$ $2$'s, the number $66$ contributes $1$, the number $68$ contributes $2$, $70$ gives $1$, $72$ gives $3$, and so on. Add up.

Comment: A few proofs of Legendre's formula at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110553/understanding-the-proof-of-a-formula-for-pe-vert-n . I proved it by induction, you don't often see that.

Comment: @WillJagy The appropriate phrase here is "Like a boss."

Comment: @PeterTamaroff or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s__rX_WL100

Comment: @WillJagy You mean http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NisCkxU544c

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, actually the Madonna song is pretty stupid. Never really listened to it before. This, however, is very nice. The comment in the text is correct, Paillard recorded two versions, and I think this is the one I prefer; I will continue checking. What I remember in particular is the plucked string instrument... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxVE6d3Yj8

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, the Like a Boss song is quite good. Never heard of it before, but then, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

Take your number, and cross out odds. You get $$130\cdot 128\cdot\;\cdots \;\cdot 68\cdot 66\cdot 64$$

Now, divide through $2$, to get $$65\cdot 64\cdot\; \cdots\; \cdot 34\cdot 33\cdot 32$$

In this step we collected $65-32+1=34$ that is $2^{34}$.
Cross out odds, $$64\cdot 62\cdot 60\cdot \;\cdots\; \cdot 36\cdot 34\cdot 32$$ divide, $$32\cdot 31\cdot\;\cdots \;\cdot 16$$ and we collected $32-16+1=17$, that is $2^{17}$. Cross out odds, divide, to get $$16\cdot 15\cdots\;\cdots\;\cdot 8$$ so we collected $16-8+1=9$, so $2^9$. Finally $8\cdot 7\cdot 6 \cdot 5\cdot 4$, collected $2^5$, $4\cdot 3\cdot 2$, collected $2^3$, and $2^2$; $2$. The final count is then $$2^{34+17+9+5+3+2+1}=2^{71}$$

[*Wolfram approved*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=130%21%2F63%21%2F%282%5E%2871%29%29+mod+2)

Comment: thanks i think i miscounted by $1$

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour Oh, it does look [like it.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B3%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B4%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B3%2B1%2B2%2B2%2B5%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B3%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B4%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B3%2B1%2B2%2B1%2B7%2B1)

Answer (score 0):

Writing your product this way should help:
$$
(2^6-1)(2^6)(2^6+1)\times \dots \times (2^7)(2^7+1)(2^7+2)
$$
$\Longrightarrow$
\begin{align*}
6+1+2+1+3+1+2+1+4+1+2+&\\1+3+1+2+1+5+1+2+1+3+1+&\\2+1+4+1+2+1+3+1+2+1+7+&1 =71\\
\end{align*}