# Can we use Legendre's formula for composite numbers?

Tags: number-theory

In the wiki article for Legendre's formula [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Legendre%27s%20formula%20gives,formula%2C%20after%20Alphonse%20de%20Polignac.), it is said the formula is for prime number, but after reading this simply amazing explanation of the formula in this [mse post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/711686/688539), I think that it can be used for knowing how many times a composite number goes into another number. For example, consider the number of times $4$ goes into 5!, it is given as:

$$ \lfloor \frac{5}{4} \rfloor$$

Which is one, and is exactly the number of times $4$ is a factor of the above. Does this always work or am I missing something?

Comment: For a counterexample, change your 5 to a 6.

Comment: Hmm it failed.. but I don't get why @Karl

Comment: The 2 and the 6 in $6!$ together contribute an extra factor of 4 that Legendre's formula "doesn't see" because they aren't multiples of 4.

Comment: But $\left\lfloor\frac {5}{4}\right\rfloor$ is not $2$ - it's $1$. Which, to your point, is indeed the power of $4$ that divides evenly into $5!$, although "one and a half" would be closer as there is still a factor of $2$ left in $120/4^1=30$.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get the issue now

Comment: Btw, you can get the desired result for a composite number by applying Legendre's formula separately to each of its prime factors and taking a minimum: $\max\{k:m^k|n\}=\min_{p|m}\lfloor \nu_p(n)/\nu_p(m)\rfloor$.

Comment: @Karl what's the idea behind the formula you have written?

Comment: The idea is that $m^k|n$ iff every prime power in the prime factorization of $m^k$ divides $n$. So we look at how many of each prime we can "fit into" $n$. Each prime gives us a different "largest possible $k$", so the smallest of those bounds is our actual answer.

Comment: If you play around with some examples and pay attention to the prime factorizations, you'll see what's going on.